# Selenium: Finding HTML5 list elements

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, gui-testing

From the following html(which is part of a drop down Menu), I need to find the element "Hello World" and click the link

```
<li data-name="Tools Menu"> <a href="javascript:void(0);">Tools</a>
    <ul>
          <li data-name="Test Menu"><a href="/Menu/Index">Test</a>
          </li>
          <li data-name="Hello World"><a href="/HelloWorld/Hello">Hello World</a>
          </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I have the following code so far:

```
ieDriver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3));
var elements = ieDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[data-name=\"Hello World\"]"));
elements.Click();
```

However, its failing with the following exception:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotVisibleException : Cannot click on element
```

Comment: The clue is probably in your `ElementNotVisibleException` exception - are you _absolutely sure_ the element is visible? Maybe get Selenium to take a screenshot to double check?

Comment: When Tools menu is clicked, a drop down menu appears and my element is shown. When I do a "View Page Source", I do see the above code

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure but is it possible you click the wrong element?

```
<li data-name="Hello World">
    <a href="/HelloWorld/Hello">Hello World</a>
</li>

[data-name=\"Hello World\"]
```

So you click the li-tag instead of the a-tag, cause you searching for a attribute with the name "data-name".

Maybe this is the problem?

good luck

Answer (score 0):

The problem right here is that your code is processing faster than the page's rendering, it's something that happens quite a bit when dealing with JS or dropdown menus in a page. I suggest the following instead of the driver.FindElement method :

```
    public static IWebElement WaitForElementPresent(this IWebDriver driver, By by)
    {
        try
        {
            return new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(x => x.FindElement(by));
        }
        catch (WebDriverTimeoutException exception)
        {
            throw new AssertionException(string.Format("Element {0} was not found. Page source: {1}{2}",
                                                       by,
                                                       Environment.NewLine,
                                                       driver.PageSource),
                                                       exception);
        }
    }
```

It will basically wait until the element is visible before processing the Click() method.